How to grep -o nested square brackets and characters
I have a string below which is stored in a file aaa

333333444444aaa[aaa[[bb[b[ccc]zzz]xx[x]cc]]cc222222211111111

The left and right square brackets may not match in the string. So I want to grep all the lowercase letters and square brackets as a string. I'm using grep -o '[a-z\[\]]*' aaa to get below as a whole.

aaa[aaa[[bb[b[ccc]zzz]xx[x]cc]]cc

But it returns 3 patterns which are single lowercase letter, single left square bracket, single lowercase letter with one or more right square bracket on the right.
So I tried grep -o '[a-z\[]*' aaa. It returns 2 patterns which are lowercase letters with left square brackets, lowercase letters. That's closer to the result I want but still not correct for sure.
Is it possible to only use grep -o and square brackets matching to get the expected result?

You may want to say grep -o '[][a-z]*' aaa.

@tshiono Thank you so much. It works as expected. But the search pattern seems so strange. Could you explain it to me?

When we want to include a right square bracket ] in a character class (as a literal character), we can put it immediately after the opening square bracket [.

@tshiono Thanks. Because backslash escape is not allowed in square brackets matching. As you said, the literal right square bracket ] must be placed right after the opening square bracket [ (or right after the [^) . And the [ literal left bracket's position in square brackets actually  doesn't matter.

I suspect all the downvotes and close votes (none mine) are because it's very difficult to understand  what you're trying to do. You say "The left and right square brackets may not match in the string" but then you say "So I want to grep all the lowercase letters and square brackets as a string." which contradicts that, as does your code. You then also say "It returns 2 patterns which are lowercase letters with left square brackets, lowercase letters." but your code would output many more than 2 strings and that seems to be what you want. If you showed the expected output that would help.

Or is aaa[aaa[[bb[b[ccc]zzz]xx[x]cc]]cc the expected output? I thought it was the actual output you're currently getting that you don't want since you said "I'm using grep -o '[a-z\[\]]*' aaa to get below" but then that's not what that grep command you provided would output so I really can't tell. If it IS the expected output then what did you mean by "The left and right square brackets may not match in the string." since that string clearly does contain the matching left and right square brackets.

@EdMorton Thank you for your patience. Those downvotes really made me hesitate to ask questions again if not seeing your comments. Now I finally know where my problem is.  As for the original string 333333444444aaa[aaa[[bb[b[ccc]zzz]xx[x]cc]]cc222222211111111, left and right square brackets do mismatch. But the example may be too obscure, I should have used one left square bracket and three right square brackets instead. Anyway thanks for pointing out my problems. Next time I will describe my questions clearly and just paste the code and results.

Since you did not tell grep to do otherwise, it is using POSIX Basic Regular Expression syntax. Your regex includes a bracket expression followed by a lone right bracket followed by an asterix:
grep -o '[a-z\[\]]*'

→
[a-z\[\]
]
*

So, your expression tells grep to look for:

a single character (a to z; or backslash; or left bracket); then
zero or more right brackets

Backslashes are not special inside a BRE bracket expression. Nor are left brackets.
As the reference above states, and @tshiono notes in the comments, to include a right bracket inside the bracket expression it must appear first.
This leads to the slightly odd looking regex [][a-z] or, equivalently, the even odder looking []a-z[].

Had you used grep's -E option you would have seen the same result since "The rules for ERE Bracket Expressions are the same as for Basic Regular Expressions".
However, if your grep supports -P (Perl syntax), your original regex would give the result you intended.

Thank you so much for your detailed explanation. Now I get the idea how to match square brackets in bracket expression.

You’re on the right track with grep, but as you noticed, grep alone struggles with matching balanced square brackets because it doesn’t support recursive patterns or balancing logic.
However, you can use this approach to get closer to your desired result:
grep -o '^[a-z\[\]]*' aaa

Explanation:
^[a-z[]]* matches any sequence of lowercase letters and square brackets from the start of the line up until the first non-matching character (like a number).
The -o flag makes grep print only the matching part of each line, so it will output something close to what you’re looking for.
Using this pattern, you should get:
aaa[aaa[[bb[b[ccc]zzz]xx[x]cc]]cc

This solution doesn’t handle perfectly balanced brackets (for that, you'd need a more advanced tool like awk or a scripting language like Python). But if you only need to capture up to the first sequence of lowercase letters and brackets, this should work well!

@Thomas I tried your answer but returns nothing. I guess that's because the ^ character makes grep searches the pattern at the start of the line. So it didn't work.
